# Can a UA Warforged Envoy pick a land vehicle as his integrated tool?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, racial-traits, vehicles, warforged

I am aware that a Warforged Envoy picking anything but the tools in the PHB on page 154 is probably against RAI and would be an awkward implementation. But is it RAW?

The [Warforged Envoy](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf)'s Integrated Tool (WGtE, p. 69 - the version quoted here is as it appears in [UA: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=9)) feature says:

> Choose a tool you're proficient with. It becomes integrated into your body, and you double your proficiency bonus for any ability checks you make with it. You must have your hands free to use this tool.

Backgrounds such as [Sailor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds/sailor) and [Soldier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds/soldier) include "vehicles (land)" and "vehicles (water)" as "Tool Proficiencies" (PHB, p. 139-40). Furthermore, *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* includes "Land and Water Vehicles" under the section titled ["Tool Proficiencies"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#ToolProficiencies). It is organized alphabetically between "Jeweler's Tools" and "Leatherworker's Tools" (XGtE, p. 82).

Then it seems that vehicles are tools that you can have a proficiency with, and therefore can have integrated in your warforged envoy.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Robots in disguise...

Comment: Note: the warforged race will be updated in WGTE when *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* is released. [Jeremy Crawford has indicated in an interview here](https://www.whatwouldthesmartpartydo.com/2019/10/29/jeremy-crawford-interview/) (summarized in [this post](https://www.enworld.org/threads/interview-with-jeremy-crawford-on-eberron-rising-from-the-last-war.668267/)) that warforged will no longer have subraces, though they'll still have some options for customization. I've clarified the description in the question accordingly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## "Warforged, roll out!"

The Integrated Tool feature says (emphasis mine):

> Choose **a tool you're proficient with**. It becomes integrated into your body, and you double your proficiency bonus for any ability checks you make with it. You must have your hands free to use this tool.

So RAW this means **any** tool you are proficient with is eligible. So the question becomes whether something is a tool.

For the RAW, I would assume anything listed in the Tools table in the PHB (p. 154) counts, as well as anything listed in similar list in later books.

The last line of the Tools table lists "**Vehicles (land or water)**", so by RAW they should qualify. This is further empowered by the fact that the Sailor (PHB p. 139) and Soldier (PHB p. 140) list "vehicles (water)" and "vehicles (land)" as Tool Proficiencies respectively.

So yes, RAW vehicles could be integrated into a Warforged Envoy.

### Beyond RAW

As a DM, I would rein this in a bit for instance by only allowing person-sized vehicles. So you can integrate a small rowboat or a cart or sled (PHB p. 157) - something you'd maybe able to carry 2 other people in, but not really self-powered.

Having said that, I could very easily see other DMs saying no to the idea. So if you want to actually use this feature this way, discuss it with your DM first.

So no, you could not be an integrated Air Galleon (though this might be an idea for a *Knight Rider* one-shot...)

Comment: You couldn’t be an inflated air galleon because that would be an air vehicle, not a water or land vehicle. Air vehicles aren’t on the tools table.

Answer (score 11):

## Ask your DM

There seems to be a split between the RAW and the Rules as Intended. Ask your DM if you want to do this and see what they want to go with.

#### RAW: Probably

The Integrated Tool feature says:

> Choose a tool you're proficient with. It becomes integrated into your
> body, and you double your proficiency bonus for any ability checks you
> make with it. You must have your hands free to use this tool.

So, to qualify for Integrated Tool something must be 1) a tool that 2) you are proficient with.

Vehicles appear to be listed as tools. If you look in the Sailor background for example it says:

> **Tool Proficiencies:** Navigator's tools, vehicles (water)

And the last entry in the Tools table in the PHB (p 154) says:

> Vehicles (land or water)

The slight ambiguity comes from the fact that Vehicles are then described in their own section apart from all the other tools, an indication that maybe the rules treat them as different from normal tools. However, it seems that when you take everything together that this objection doesn't really negate the fact that vehicles are literally listed as tools in the table and are listed as tools in proficiencies as well. So, the rules seem to consider them tools.

So, if your character takes a background that gives you a vehicle tool proficiency (such as sailor or soldier), then you should meet both requirements and technically should be able to use it for your Integrated Tool feature.

#### Design intent: No (ask your DM)

According to [Keith Baker's FAQ on *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*](http://keith-baker.com/wgte-faq/):

> **An envoy warforged has an integrated tool that’s part of its body, and
> gains expertise with that tool. In the PHB, tool proficiencies
> provided by backgrounds include vehicles. So can I have a warforged
> with a built-in wagon?**
>
> All things require the approval of the DM. If your DM WANTS to let you
> have a warforged with a built in boat, that’s great. But the design
> intent is that this applies to the specifically identified tools
> listed on page 154 of the *Player’s Handbook*. **This does not include
> mounts and vehicles, which are detailed on the following page
> (“vehicles” are on 154, but not detailed).** So again, if you and your
> DM agree, go for it. But **it is not the design intent.**