# Can a UA warforged envoy have an integrated airship?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, vehicles, warforged

We know that [Warforged envoys can have a vehicle as their integrated tool](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136735/can-a-warforged-envoy-pick-a-land-vehicle-as-his-integrated-tool/136748#136748). I had [assumed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136735/can-a-ua-warforged-envoy-pick-a-land-vehicle-as-his-integrated-tool/136748#comment416270_136748) that this had to be a land or water vehicle. However, the D&D beyond character generator lists “Vehicles (sea/air)” as a tool proficiency option. From my understanding, [D&D beyond is a canon D&D source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114911/is-dd-beyond-an-official-rules-source/114912#114912). If “Vehicles (sea/air)” is a canon tool proficiency option, this means that warforged can have an integrated airship.

**So, RAW, can warforged envoys have an integrated airship?**

Note: I know that this is not RAI. My question is about strict RAW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### As of this date, No, a warforged cannot by RAW integrate an airship.

Due to the *Player's Handbook* chapter 5 (Equipment) sections 'Tools' (page 154) and 'Mounts and Vehicles' (page 155), it seems that vehicles are considered to be a type of tool, allowing them to be chosen for Integrated Tool. But they only state 'land or water' vehicles.

Further, while the airship is listed within the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (table on page 119), including being able to be owned by the players, it is not listed among the vehicles that the player can obtain proficiency in within the *Player's Handbook*.

Given that the airship is listed in the core 3 books, but is not among the options for proficiency, it seems players were not intended to have skill in its use.

As players could not obtain proficiency in air vehicles, they would not be eligible for the Envoy's Integrated Tool.

For this reason, I think the listing on DND Beyond is likely in error, especially as its listings for vehicle proficiencies are: 'Land', 'Sea/Air', 'Water'. The fact that there is a 'Sea/Air' option, as well as a 'Water' option, seems to indicate an error in the listings (since 'sea' and 'water' vehicles are the same).

Finally, while players could train (*Player's Handbook*, chapter 8 Adventuring, Between Adventures) to gain proficiency in airships, the text for warforged envoy does not indicate that the player can change what their Integrated Tool is, thus even after gaining proficiency in airships, they would not be eligible for Integrated Tool.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes by RAW if DND Beyond is official

The PHB page 154 lists Vehicles (land/water) as a Tool. However it is marked to see the "mounts and vehicles" section. On page 157 of the PHB it lists the specific types of vehicles for land or water. Some modules such as, Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus show new vehicles. The Eberron playtest (which is soon to be released as official) have airships. If DND Beyond is truly official and that notation being Vehicles (sea/air) was not a mistake, we can assume that the "air" part was added for the Eberron campaign. If you choose a specific airship for your integrated tool it would be allowed.

Comment: This answer could be improved by saying _how_ you know why the sea tag was added; now it just sounds like you are pulling it from thin air.

Comment: @MrHiTech I see your point. I guess I was assuming that point based on logic. Since I do not work for DND Beyond I do not know for sure so I removed that sentence.

Comment: Not sure we can trust DNDBeyond to be accurate, as there are mistakes present on it (such as Ranger Favored Enemy options).

Comment: @Journer That is why I said if it is truly official and if it was not a mistake.