# If a UA warforged envoy's integrated vehicle is damaged, does it regain hit points when its warforged host takes a long rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, rests, vehicles, warforged

Let’s say the following were to happen:

A [UA warforged envoy](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf#page=9) has an [integrated longship](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136735/can-a-warforged-envoy-pick-a-land-vehicle-as-his-integrated-tool/136748#136748). Their party is traveling along, when suddenly enemy pirates attack! The party emerges victorious, but the longship-warforged has sustained damage. As the party wonders how to repair the sails in the middle of the ocean, the warforged’s player comes up with a spectacular idea: “Wait, he says, I can just take a long rest! If the ship is part of me, and I regain all my hit points from a long rest, my ship should regain all its hit points when I finish a long rest!”

**Going by strict RAW, should this work?**

Comment: This question is honestly overly specific, and could just be: Is a Warforged Integrated Tool repaired due to a long rest?

Comment: @Journer Tools don’t generally have hit points, vehicles do.

Comment: True, but the core books do have rules for non-vehicles having hit points, and this question does really at its core go further than vehicles.

Comment: Is there a reason why you accepted an answer and edited the question to make that same answer mildly obsolete? Are you looking for adjusted answers, or was that edit in error?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I edited to correct the error in my question (about the airship) because there was a new answer in [that question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159086/can-a-warforged-have-an-integrated-airship/159087#159087) that explained why it wouldn’t be possible. I therefore edited to correct that error, but I still agree with the answer (other than the fact that it uses the word “airship”.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll be honest I do feel my answer is now obsolete and will update it only after I understand the existing rules regarding repairing vehicles. I would delete it but it is currently accepted so I cannot do so

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### There are no rules for this; the situation you've described doesn't exist yet; ask your GM

There are (as of now) no rules at all for how the situation you've described would be resolved so ask your GM. In fact, there aren't even rules for repairing airships whatsoever, let alone during a long rest while they are an integrated tool. Any content from Eberron is still playtest as of now so we would have to wait for further details on how those rules work. Finally you've asked us to assume something which very well may not even be possible, a Warforged choosing an airship as an integrated tool.

At the very least the section on "[Long Rests](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#LongRest)" states:

> [...] At the end of a long rest, a character regains all lost hit points [...]

Personally I would not call the vehicle "the character", it is an integrated tool, and no part of that description says that you suddenly share hit points.

Finally the intent of the integrated tool is that it **does not apply to vehicles**. According to [Keith Baker's FAQ on *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*](http://keith-baker.com/wgte-faq/):

> **An envoy warforged has an integrated tool that’s part of its body, and gains expertise with that tool. In the PHB, tool proficiencies provided by backgrounds include vehicles. So can I have a warforged with a built-in wagon?**
>
> All things require the approval of the DM. If your DM WANTS to let you have a warforged with a built in boat, that’s great. But the design intent is that this applies to the specifically identified tools listed on page 154 of the *Player’s Handbook*. **This does not include mounts and vehicles, which are detailed on the following page (“vehicles” are on 154, but not detailed).** So again, if you and your DM agree, go for it. But **it is not the design intent.**